# What is the best photo stitching software available?

Tags: photos, panorama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open source Panorama maker for windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8047/open-source-panorama-maker-for-windows)

I've been taking a load of shots with my Canon 400D recently with the intention of stitching them together to create some nice big panoramic photos. I've had a few tries at this before using various different bits of software and none of them seem to be without their faults (most produce peculiar errors on at least some series of shots and some require more interaction than others).

So far I've tried:

- [PTGui](http://www.ptgui.com/)
- [Canon Photostitch](http://download.cnet.com/Canon-Utilities-PhotoStitch/3000-18489_4-199151.html)
- [The Panorama Factory](http://www.panoramafactory.com/)

It doesn't have to be free if it gives good results every time.

What software does everyone else use / recommend for this?

Comment: This has been answered before. Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/15946/how-to-make-a-cyclorama and http://superuser.com/questions/8047/open-source-panorama-maker-for-windows and http://superuser.com/questions/41684/panoramic-picture-stitchers

Comment: also http://superuser.com/questions/43868/how-do-i-merge-an-array-of-images-into-a-single-giant-image/43901#43901

Comment: Thanks for the links guys - not sure why I didn't find those when I searched!

Comment: No problem. The thing is you searched for stitching when you could have tried panorama. That would have given you quite a lot of results.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/product/computational-photography-applications/image-composite-editor/) recently and it worked pretty well!

It's free and easy to use.